# How to set value to text field in html page, for dynamically generated checkbox fields using forms django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, checkbox, django-forms

I setup quiz app, where choice field(Multiple choice) is dynamically added using the django form set. This choice is checkbox type, i want to pass value to text field if i checked the checkbox.My problem is, i cant write a function to set value to text field, because the checkbox is dynamic.

i tried to get the total no of checkbox displayed to the page and created thus much text box also. I tried a jquery which will set val to text field, if i checked checkbox. writing code for each checkbox is not possible because checkbox it dynamic.Is there any method in JavaScript to make it work.?

test.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'polls:checkanswer' question.id %}" method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}

            {% for choice in question.testchoice_set.all %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choices{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
                <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_opt }}</label><br />
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
            <input type="text" name="nvalue" id="nvalue">
     </form>
     <script>
    var totalCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox').length;
    $("#nvalue").val(totalCheckboxes);
    var i;
    //dynamically creating textboxes based on no of checkbox
    for (i = 1; i <= totalCheckboxes ; i++) {
        m = i;
        var i = document.createElement("input"); 
        i.type = "text";
        document.body.appendChild(i);
        i.value = "";
        //i.hidden = true; 
        i.id = 'choice'+m;
        i = m;
    }
    //set value to text field, if first checkbox is checked.
    $("#choices1").click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
         $("#choice1").val("Yes");
    }
    else {
         $("#choice1").val("No");
    }
    });
```

If i checked any checkboxes in the page, i need to set 'yes' to corresponding text field.

Comment: What text field? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm generating the check boxes based on the choices in my model(if i given 5 choices for a question, five checkbox will appear in html page). So if a question has multiple correct answer  i need to check it with my model whether its correct or not. I can check it for single answer.

Answer (score 0):

set class attribute to every checkbox, say class = "c", and do

```
$('.c).each(function(){if($(this).prop("checked")) {$(this).val("Yes");}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, instead of passing 'Yes' i passed the id to text field and check it with database model.

```
<script>
  var checkbox=[];
  var i=1;
  $('.cbstyle').change(function()
  {
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         checkbox.push($(this).val());
  } 
  else 
  {
     for (var i=checkbox.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
     {
         if (checkbox[i] === $(this).val()) 
             checkbox.splice(i, 1);
     }
  }
  $('#txtchoice4').val(checkbox.join(','));
});
</script>
```